# How to make android application for responsive website

Tags: android, android-studio, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, mobile-application

I am having mobile compatible website, it is highly responsive and do all what I need in mobile.
I just like to have an android/ios application, either it can represent my website as container.
Do we have any tool for the same. Is there any way to achieve it, as I do not want to use any mobile hardware like camera, geolocation and any other.

If any container of android or ios can provide a simple interface by opening my site in it, it will be a great option.

Kindly share your view on the same.

Comment: You have already mentioned phonegap in the tags. All you have to do is placing a  web view in your mobile app, then it will show your website. Isn't it what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) about layouts.
A mobile application provides a different user experience than a mobile website. In your case if you don't want to use the mobile version of your site in the browser, then you need to create an application with a native UI.

Answer (score 0):

### For Android:

In my opinion, you should consider using the Empty Activity template from Android Studio to add a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) inside it that will point to your website.

### For iOS:

Seems like iOS Dev kit has [the same kind of view](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview).

### For Windows Universal Apps:

Their Dev Kit has [it as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).

### Alternative:

If you feel more comfortable with web technologies, you can consider using [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) to build a mobile app from web sources.

### Conclusion

All the native solutions presented are not that hard to implement (Less than a few hours), they just need you to play a little bit around with the native developing.

Cordova, the web-to-mobile solution, would also need you to play around with it.

Happy mobile developing !